# View list of files restored from Azure File Share

Tags: azure-backup-vault, azure-file-share

While a colleague was trying to restore a file from an Azure File Share backed up using Azure Recovery Vault he somehow managed to run the restore for the entire share rather than just the individual files that were needed.

As soon as he realised what he had done he cancelled the job and contacted me.
The restore job says Number Of Restored Files 25000+. But how do we view a list of these 25000+ files to know what has been affected.

Looking at log analytics it seems to only contain high level information about the backup/restore jobs. Even the new Backup Reports feature in Backup Center does not seem to allow you to drill down into the job information.